# Keycloak skipping a Authentication flow ( Choose User)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, freemarker, keycloak, keycloak-services

Using keycloak 4.1 version. Added Custom flow to reset password to send SMS OTP instead of email.

Step 1 : Choose user ( Validates a user)
Step 2 : Send OTP and validate form
Step 3 : Reset password

I am facing a problem in step 2. If user already authenticated and click back from step 2, I can't go to step 1 to enter another user id / email id. It skips that step 1 and keep on coming directly to step 2 "Send and validate otp  form" when clicking back or clicking forgot password link again.

Step one configured as requiresUser() **False** and Step2 configured requiresUser() **True**

Is there any way to restart session / flow when clicking back **${url.loginResetCredentialsUrl}** in ftl file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are developing something that is managed by administrator who can reset passwords of different users and that trigger sending a message. I think you can just logout the user via javaScript in your ftl file and then try to redirect him to step 1. You can find in admin panel of keycloak what request is sending via network panel in dev tools when you click logout session for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use **${url.getLoginRestartFlowUrl()}** to restart login flow. That will reset user session information.